# How to log response time for all Guzzle requests

Tags: symfony, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle as a http client in a Symfony app. With the following code I'm able to log all requests and responses. Is there a way to log also response time?

I tried [on_stats](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#on-stats) but it should be added to each client call and it is not an option.

```yaml
services:
  app.client.default:
    class: 'GuzzleHttp\Client'
    lazy: true
    arguments:
      - handler: '@app.handler_stack.default'

  app.handler_stack.default:
    class: 'GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack'
    factory: [ GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack, create ]
    calls:
      - [ push, [ '@app.middleware.log_default', 'log_default' ] ]

  app.middleware.log_default:
    class: callback
    factory: [ GuzzleHttp\Middleware, log ]
    arguments:
      - '@logger'
      - '@app.log_formatter.default'

  app.log_formatter.default:
    class: 'GuzzleHttp\MessageFormatter'
    arguments:
      - ">>>>>>>>\n{request}\n<<<<<<<<\n{response}\n--------\n{error}"

  app.service:
    class: 'App\Service'
    arguments:
      - '@app.client.default'
```

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class Service {

    private $httpClient;

    public function __construct(Client $httpClient) {
       $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
    }

    public function apiRequest() {
        $response = $this->httpClient->get('https://www.google.com');
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this bundle solve your issue https://github.com/shrikeh/guzzle-middleware-responsetimer?

Comment: Might be an option, thank you